# How to use special characters as user input

Tags: command-line, special-characters

I want to use user input of special characters in conditional statement.
I tried:

```
read -p "press arrow up" foo
if [ $foo == "^[[A" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

It did not do what I wanted it to do.

Comment: You could do: `if [ "$foo" = "$(xxd -r <<< "00000000: 1b5b 410a")" ];`, but there might be a better option.

Comment: @pLumo Is there a map for all special characters for this format: (xxd -r <<< "00000000: 1b5b 410a"?

Comment: No, I just made `xxd <<< "$foo"` and copy-pasted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you could use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "press arrow up " foo

if [ "$foo" = $'\e[A' ]; then
  echo 'yes'
fi
```

For a more nuanced version, see [BASH question: using read, can I capture a single char OR arrow key (on keyup)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480091/65304)

Answer (score 2):

Not especially beautiful, but you could compare hex values.

To find out hex value of up arrow, assign `foo` manually and run

```bash
xxd <<< "$foo"
```

Copy paste the output to your script and use `xxd -r` to revert the hex value:

```bash
up_arrow="$(xxd -r <<< "00000000: 1b5b 410a")"
if [ "$foo" = "$up_arrow" ]; then echo yes; fi
```